# How to Integrate Import Export CSV / XLS product opencart

Tags: csv, import, export, opencart

How to set Import export product in opencart?

I have lots of extensions.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCart there is no built-in module to export/import, so you need to use extension or some script. There are lots of modules for this. I use [Store Manager](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=20400), though it is paid. However, if you need it one-time you can download 2-week version and perform task costless.